# Difference between "get out of" and "get away with"

Tags: american-english, british-english

I have two questions:

First question: what is the exact meaning of "get away with"? For example in this sentence "Do you think I can get away with wearing pants?". Does it mean "I don't feel like to wear anything else"?

And the second question is: What is difference between "get out of" and "get away with"?

For example, in the sentence "My boss called me a meeting, and I couldn't get out of it", can I use "get away with it" instead of "get out of it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.Do you think I can get away with wearing pants?

This could be a question from an employee of an organisation that requires ladies to wear skirts or dresses.

> 2. My boss called me [for] a meeting, and I couldn't get out of it.

> get out of it

> get away with it

Both phrasal verbs are defined further down in Cambridge Dictionary.

Using *get out of it* is more appropriate for this example.

> get out of sth

> — phrasal verb with get verb

> to avoid doing something that you do not want to do, especially by giving an excuse:

> I think her backache was just a way of getting out of the housework.

> get away with sth

> — phrasal verb with get verb

> to succeed in avoiding punishment for something:

> If I thought I could get away with it, I wouldn't pay my taxes at all.

[get out of sth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-out-of-sth)

[get away with sth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-away-with-sth)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

They are not interchangeable. Here is a dictionary:

[get away with](https://www.lexico.com/definition/get_away_with)
[get out of](https://www.lexico.com/definition/get_out_of)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question first:

To *get out of* doing something is to find a way of not having to do it.

To *get away with* doing something is to do it without looking foolish or inappropriate, or without being punished (depending what it is!).

"Do you think I can get away with wearing pants?" (presumably said by an American woman!) suggests that she would like to wear trousers to a social event where they might be considered too informal.

Comment: I am very grateful for your good explanation.